# Python 2.7.11 - ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit - Kali Linux / Debian 8

Tags: python, linux, debian, qtwebkit

I'm trying to launch an app dependant on QtWebKit but i'm unable to import the module. I've tried debugging by launching python and importing other modules. They all work fine (e.g. from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore) works without any issues, but when i run

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit
```

I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit
```

I have also tried the following to no avail (they install fine but do not fix the issue):

```
apt-get install --reinstall python-qt4
apt-get install --reinstall python-2.7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with the app, sparta?.
Debian Stretch which Kali Rolling is based on has [mothballed](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/05/msg00001.html) QtWebKit in PyQt4.

The latest version does not contain QtWebkit.so.

Unfortunately the code in question needs to be updated to use an alternative such as PyQt5 equivalent module.

A bug report concerning this can be found on the kali bug report site from Jun/2/2016

---

### optional bodge/quick n dirty fix [works in latest build of Kali]

In the mean time and if it is sparta and you need it functional now:
apt-get install python-pyside.qtwebkit
clone a copy from https://github.com/SECFORCE/sparta to where ever suits, in my case /opt/recon/sparta, this preserves the system version so it can fixed updated normally.
edit sparta.py

remove QtWebKit from line 22
insert the code from line 26 to 30

```
21 try: 
22    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
23 except:
24    print "[-] Import failed. PyQt4 library not found. \nTry installing it with: apt-get install python-qt4"
25    exit()
26 try:
27    from PySide import QtWebKit
28 except:
29    print "[-] Import failed. QtWebkit library not found. \nTry installing it with: apt-get install python-pyside.qtwebkit"
30    exit()
```

edit ui/view.py
comment out line 15

```
15 #from PyQt4 import QtWebKit                                              # to show html code (help menu)
16 from PySide import QtWebKit                                              # to show html code (help menu)
```

edit line 54 the original can be seen below

```
54 self.helpWidget.load(QUrl('./doc/help.html'))
```

This should be modified to

```
54 self.helpWidget.load('./doc/help.html')
```

Disclaimer This is a 5 minute fix, look to the project homepage for longterm fix.

Comment: Excellent thanks! This has me up and running for now.

Answer (score 0):

On latest version sparta and Kali:

Linux kali 4.14.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.2-1kali1 (2017-12-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

You need modify:

Comment :

16 #from PyQt4 import QtWebKit

Add:

17 from PySide import QtWebKit

Modify:

54  self.helpWidget.load('./doc/help.html')

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately developers have no time and resources to fix the issue permanently. But you can get updated and compatible with Kali version here
https://github.com/alexxn/sparta

Answer (score 0):

install python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit

the solution is here:
https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin/issues/56#issuecomment-387223048

worked for me